# How can I plot a circle with a given radius and a dot to indicate the center of the circle at the same time?

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny, shiny-server

I can already plot a city with a circle of a particular radius; what I can't figure out is how to mark the center of the circle with a dot.  I'm using R, Shiny, and leaflet.

```
observe({
        map$clearShapes()
        cities <- topCitiesInBounds()

    if (nrow(cities) == 0)
      return()


    map$addCircle(
      cities$Lat,
      cities$Long,
      sqrt(cities[[popCol()]]) * radiusFactor * 35 / max(5, input$map_zoom)^2, 
      row.names(cities),
      list(
        weight=1.2,
        fill=TRUE,
        color='#4A9'
      ) 
    )


  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You example is not reproducible so hard to help you.  But I assume that you have a data.frame cities with Lat ang Long informations.

You can add a marker:

```
paramList <- dlply(cities, 2, function(x) {
        list(x[['Lat']], 
             x[['Long']], 
             x[['id']]})
        )})
lapply(paramList1, function(x) do.call(map$addMarker, unname(x)))
```